# MVC5 there is an error in this statement @Html.Raw("<ul class='@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.circleLevel)'>")

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

[this how it looks when i run the code while ul closing inside for each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPDi1.jpg) and [this how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvPQg.jpg) when i compile my code a syntax error appears in this line 
@Html.Raw(" item1.circleLevel)'>")
 i don't know how to correct it

```
    int num = 0;
    foreach (var item1 in Model)
    {
        if (num != item1.level)
        {
            num = item1.level;
         @Html.Raw("<ul class=\"@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.circleLevel)\">")
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    if (item1.level == item.level)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a class="text" style="background-color: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsExest)" href="@Url.Action("Details", "Tree", new { id = item.User_ID })">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                }
                <li>
                    <div class="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="add family member">@Html.ActionLink("+", "Create")</div>
                </li>


                    <ul class="circle5"></ul>




        }
    }
   @Html.Raw("</ul>") 
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: (CS1003: Syntax error, ','expected) this is the error

Comment: Why are you using `@Html.Raw()`? Just `<ul class="item1.circleLevel">`

Comment: i want to close the ul tag outside the foreach  so the shapes of the circles be above each other

Comment: That makes no sense - you need balanced (equal numbers of) `<ul>` and `</ul>`. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ok but i want to close it outside the foreach i will update the question so you can see how it should looks and how it looks when i run the code when i add the ul tag closing inside foreach

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Closing it outside would result in invalid html. You have not shown you css so its near impossible to help. Perhaps creating a simple fiddle would help to understand what you want to achieve.